# How to select the first object from an array and check the value of one of it's properties with Postman

Tags: postman

I have the task to with Postman to create a test in which I have to check if the "gender" in the first object of the array below is "M".
I tried with my limited knowledge to make it work, but it seems that I am far from anywhere.
I red whatever info I could find, but nothing made sense for this particular case.

From this example:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1234567,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "date_of_birth": "1990-01-01",
        "gender": "M",
        "eye_color": "Blue",
        "height": 175
    },
    {
        "id": 2345678,
        "first_name": "Jane",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "date_of_birth": "1985-05-15",
        "gender": "F",
        "eye_color": "Brown",
        "height": 162
    },
    {
        "id": 3456789,
        "first_name": "Michael",
        "last_name": "Johnson",
        "date_of_birth": "1978-11-30",
        "gender": "M",
        "eye_color": "Green",
        "height": 180
    },
    {
        "id": 4567890,
        "first_name": "Emily",
        "last_name": "Williams",
        "date_of_birth": "1992-07-20",
        "gender": "F",
        "eye_color": "Hazel",
        "height": 165
    }
]
```

I suppose it is far from what the true answer might be, but this is where I am right now.

```
pm.test("first object gender is male", () => {
   const jsonData = pm.response.json()
   expect({'gender': 1}).to.have.property('gender', 'M');

});
```

Comment: Just type `jsonData[0]` to select the first element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the first JSON object from the array, using `jsonData[0]`, and the perform a test as follows,

```
 pm.test("first object gender is male", () => {
   const jsonData = pm.response.json()
   pm.expect(jsonData[0].gender).to.eql("M");

});
```